# Android Create View of Display

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to create a `View` of the current display so I can call the following methods to create a `Bitmap`:

```
 v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 current = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache(), 1686, 136, (631-168), (343-136));
 v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

To create the `View` I tried this line

```
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
```

I got the error "Symbol 'mCurrentUrlMask' cannot be resolved."

I'm looking to create a bitmap of a section of the screen, and thoughts you have on this issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: who is `mCurrentUrlMask` ?

Comment: It was something I saw on stackoverflow

Comment: nice Sir, anyways always upvote helpful post and if it solves a problem accept it, happy coding sir, be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

```
View v1 = MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView();//editted
v1.buildDrawingCache();
//your rest of the code. 
// you will get a bitmap of the whole screen.
```

or you could use `ViewSnapper`

Comment: I tried this and got the non-static method .getWindow() cannot be accessed from a static context. I'm using this code in the onStop(){} method.

Comment: Also .getWindow gets the current window for the activity. I'm looking to get the current screen regardless of what activity is in the foreground, this is in onStop(){} so it won't be in the foreground.

Comment: you made me smile; the `Activity.` was suppose to be your own activity reference okay, like `this.getWindow()` you get me sir?@JonathanAlexander and also you will need to put that in all your `Activities` unless you use something like `ActivityGroup` or `FragmentActivity` that you can for see others you get me, or you could check [Display](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) out, but its not what you want.

Comment: Oh okay I understand what you mean. I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: I did what you suggested and replaced activity with the reference to my activity (MainActivity) and got the same error. Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: did you use `MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView()`? @Jon or simply if you are calling it in on stop, just do `getWindow()`

Comment: View v1 = MainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();

That's the line I have the error on. When I do MainActivity.getWindow;  I get the same error

Comment: no sir,add this, like this `MainActivity.this` so it will be like this  `View v1 = MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView()` or let go off the mainactivity and just call this line `View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView()` open your eyes for me sir @Jon also check the editted answer

Comment: Thank you for your patients, I let go off the MainActivity and called View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView() like you said in the onStop(){} method (I want it to run when the application is in the background). Do you agree with what what I did?

Comment: when you say you want it to run in the background you mean when the Activity is not showing to the user? or you mean threads which is asynchronous? onStop() means the screen is no longer showing to the user, so yeah it will always run when an Activity shows on top of your app or a system dialog or the user presses the home key or immediately when your activity is about to be destroyed or when your screen is rotated or you manually call `onStop()` or unforeseen occurrence-the last part was just a joke, so yea i agree in that sense Sir @Jon

Comment: Is onStop() called when the user switches to another application or am I mistaken? Also you said that onStop() is called when screen is rotated, I had never read that but is it called if screen rotates outside of the application?For example if the user switched to another application that rotated the screen.

Comment: yes yes it is called, well when the screen is rotated the current showing activity is restarted or recreated-but you can double check from the docs no no unless it is rotated on your activity that is on the screen. so if your activity is not showing currently that is it is in the backstack it wont be recreated, so your example will be no @Jon if i have solved the problem you can accept and upvote, you can ask me any future questions [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77204/extended-help) that is if i am available